# The http create function in Tour Of Heroes

Tags: angular, http, angular-tour-of-heroes

I am enjoying the Tour of Heroes tutorial. Everything is working as it should but I'm really puzzled abou the http adding a hero functionality. It seems to magically know what id to assign to the new hero. I don't see any code anywhere that gets the max id of existing heroes anmd increments 1. Can someone explain?

Comment: The backend code does that. Not the frontend code.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api this is what it uses to mock a backend server

Comment: There is no backend code in this tutorial. The web api is mocked in the front end., So my question still stands, how does it know about incrementing the id property?

Answer (score 0):

It's a part of the 'in-memory-web-api' that is called as a mockup sercice.
apparenly, it creates an id in case no id is passed.
https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api#custom-genid